# Porque a página em Flutter não está começando no início por padrão?

Tags: listview, flutter, rolamento

O scrollable da página está começando em um lugar abaixo do início, não no meio, nem no final, eu pensei inicialmente que era por causa de eu estar usando uma ListView dentro de um Container, sem especificar o `height`e o `width`do Container, porém mesmo após colocar o resultado continua o mesmo, se puderem me ajudar a fazer a página começar do início agradeço, segue o código,

```
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return PlatformScaffold(
  appBar: PlatformAppBar(
    title: Text("Relatório por Unidade"),
    android: (_) => MaterialAppBarData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      leading: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.grey[200],
    child: ListView( . . .)
    )
   )
  )
 );
}
```

A página começa a assim, 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Uma observação importante é que ao tentar scrollar á página para o começo ela sobe para o início, porém logo volta a está imagem acima, 
[image: foto ao segurar a página no início]

Comment: Você está usando algum `Stack`?

Comment: Não, somente o Container e dentro o ListView. E no caso, aquele "body" é do Scaffold.

Comment: O legal seria você editar sua pergunta e colocar toda a sua árvore de Widget dessa classe em questão... As vezes você está fazendo algo de errado em outro ponto, porque essa estrutura pequena que tu mostrou, não ajuda em nada.

Comment: Vou estar postando, o unico diferente é q to usando uma biblioteca que muda a estética do Widget de acordo com a plataforma IOS ou Android.

Comment: @PauloOyama como já sugerido o ideal é você postar o código completo, ao menos da página onde o problema está acontecendo, o problema talvez possa estar nesta biblioteca que você está ultilizando, Flutter defende o uso de um Layout uniforme Material ou Cupertino ... ou um customizado, mas não os misture!  Se você precisa de layouts diferentes para plataformas diferentes, então você vai precisar escrever uma página pra IOS e outra pra Android. Atualize sua pergunta colocando ao menos o Scaffold dessa página, junto ao tipo de Scroll que você está usando.

Comment: Cara como tem a implementação do Android apenas, e o layout das imagens não condiz com a implementação, então pelo jeito tu ta usando o iOS, certo?... De onde ta vindo essa app bar com título "Relatório por Veículo"? Talvez se tu implementar o tipo iOS o erro seja corrigido.

Comment: Matheus o estilo IOS, vem do plugin Plataform, esta biblioteca permite que um Widget como por exemplo o "PlatformScaffold" tenha o mesmo estilo da plataforma IOS ou Android, então esse Widget está fazendo estilos diferentes em um só código, dependendo do SO do usuário

Comment: Você colocou que o seu Container deve ter a mesma altura em px que o tamanho da tela do aparelho, mas você está se esquecendo que você uma AppBar em cima, o que significa que o pedaço correspondente à altura da AppBar ficarà escondido inicialmente a não se que o usuário faça um scroll, tenta mudar essa altura tendo em consideração a AppBar e veja o que acontece

Comment: Eu tentei mudar para umas 2x o tamanho da tela, mas ainda sim, não deu certo o scroll ?

Comment: Experimenta colocar seu ListView dentro de um ScrollController, eu nunca tive esse problema, mas talvez possa resolver.
Talvez se você colocar toda sua arvore de widgets possamos te ajudar melhor